# Is there any way to Get Android Version in Flutter With Out Using any Plugin

Tags: android, flutter, performance, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to show Icon on the base of Android Version if Version is 11 or Greater than 11 it should show different Notification Icon but if Version is less than 11 it should show different icon currently i am using [Device Info Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) to Get Android version. is there any way to get Android Version in Flutter with out using any Library.

Comment: You could try using [Platform.operatingSystemVersion;](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform/operatingSystemVersion.html)

Comment: @Nitish i have Tried this but it does not give me android Version It gives a String that Contain some random number and text

Comment: As stated by google it's OS version only "A string representing the version of the operating system or platform." - but I guess it's not a simplified one. It might also contain build/patch version of the OS install. I guess then there is no other any besides using plugin, but keep the question open someone might know it.

Comment: You can write your own native android code "actually it's one line to check for sdk version" and use platform channels to communicate with your native android code.

Comment: Ok thanks and let see what others recommend